# Is alias necessary in query when joining?

Tags: sql

I am writing query below

```
select students.name, count(distinct student_id) as scorefreq 

from students 

left join grade on students.id = grades.student_id 

group by 1 

having count(distinct student_id) > 100
```

Is the above query correct or would I have to alias id coming from the grade table?
id coming from grade table is in the count aggregate function.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you mean _"alias"_. Since there's also an `id` column in the `students` table, you should **qualify** the `id` in the `count()`, ie `count(distinct grade.id)`. FYI, I doubt you need `distinct`

Comment: @Phil Sorry but I edited my question, my question was meant to be do I need to alias the grade table when I call for student_id or not needed? Thnx

Comment: Again, that is not an alias. I suggest you read up on SQL terminology. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm

Comment: @Phil I interpret the OP's ask as being whether or not the `student_id` column needs to be qualified by either an alias or full table name.  Answer: no, but you should always qualify every column with an alias or table name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep, I thought the same but it will definitely help OP in future if they use the right words when searching for answers

Comment: `group by 1` isn't valid ANSI/ISO SQL, but supported by some dbms products. The `1` should be `students.name` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to write your query using aliases would be:

```
select s.name, count(distinct g.student_id) as scorefreq 
from students s
left join grade g on s.id = g.student_id
group by 1 
having count(distinct g.student_id) > 100;
```

Technically speaking, you might not need an alias on the `student_id` column in the `grade` table, assuming that the `students` table does not also have a column by this name (which it probably does not).  That being said, using proper aliases is *always* the preferred way of writing a query.  To see why, imagine at some later point someone else adds a `student_id` column to `students` for whatever reason.  Immediately, your query would start breaking, because your SQL engine would not be able to resolve `student_id` to one of the two tables on its own.

If you don't want to use aliases, that is valid, but then you should still need to qualify the column you want, e.g.

```
select students.name, count(distinct grade.student_id) as scorefreq
...
```

Comment: @Tim_Biegelisen sorry but I edited my question, my question was meant to be do I need to alias the grade table when I call for student_id or not needed? Thnx

Comment: @Chris90 The answer is no, techincally speaking, you do not need an alias.  But, best practice is to include aliases.

Comment: `grade g` is an alias. `as scorefreq` is an alias. `g.student_id` or `grade.student_id` is a qualification

Comment: @Phil thanks, so it is recommended as best practice but, technically my query would run if I did not qualify my fields from the grade table correct?

Comment: @Chris90 Try it out and see `:-)` ... yes, it will probably run, but it is not best practice, and you should change it if you have control over this code.

Comment: @Chris90 take Tim's advice (they don't have a 300k+ score for nothing). By qualifying your columns, you avoid debugging unnecessary _"ambiguous column"_ errors later